# How does c++ auto_ptr relate to managed pointers (Java, C#...)

Tags: c#, java, c++, managed, auto-ptr

I come from a managed world and c++ automatic memory management is quite unclear to me

If I understand correctly, I encapsulate a pointer within a stack object and when auto_ptr becomes out of scope, it automatically calls delete on the pointed object?

What kind of usage should I make of it and how should I naturally avoid inherent c++ problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto_ptr` is the simplest implementation of [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) in C++. Your understanding is correct, whenever its destructor is called, the underlying pointer gets `delete`d.

This is a one step up from C where you don't have destructors and any meaningful RAII is impossible.

A next step up towards automagic memory management is [`shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm). It uses reference counting to keep track of whether or not the object is alive. This allows the programmer to create the objects a bit more freely, but still not as powerful as the garbage collection in Java and C#. One example where this method fails is circular references. If A has a ref counted pointer to B and B has a ref counted pointer to A, they will never get destructed, even though no other object is using either.

Modern object orianted languages use some sort of variation of [mark and sweep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29). This technique allows managing circular references and is reliable enough for most programming tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `std::auto_ptr` calls `delete` on its content when it goes out of scope. You use `auto_ptr` only if no shared ownership takes place.
`auto_ptr` isn't particularly flexible, you can't use it with objects created with `new[]` or anything else.

Shared ownership is usually approached with shared pointers, which e.g. [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) has implementations of. The most common usage, implemented e.g. in Boosts `shared_ptr`, employs a [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) scheme and cleans up the pointee when the last smart pointer goes out of scope.
`shared_ptr` has one big advantage - it lets you specify custom deleters. With that you can basically put every kind of resource in it and just have to specify what deleter it should use.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you use a smart pointer. For the sake of example, I'll be using a `shared_ptr`.

```
{
    shared_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo);
    // do things with foo
}
// foo's value is released here
```

Pretty much all smart pointers aim to achieve something similar to the above, in that the object being held in the smart pointer gets released at the end of the smart pointer's scope. However, there are three types of smart pointers that are widely used, and they have very different semantics on how ownership is handled:

1. `shared_ptr` uses "shared ownership": the `shared_ptr` can be held by more than one scope/object, and they all own a reference to the object. When the last reference falls off, the object is deleted. This is done using reference counting.
2. `auto_ptr` uses "transferable ownership": the `auto_ptr`'s value can be held only in one place, and each time the `auto_ptr` is assigned, the assignee receives ownership of the object, and the assigner loses its reference to the object. If an `auto_ptr`'s scope is exited without the object being transferred to another `auto_ptr`, the object is deleted. Since there is only one owner of the object at a time, no reference counting is needed.
3. `unique_ptr`/`scoped_ptr` uses "nontransferable ownership": the object is held only at the place it's created, and cannot be transferred elsewhere. When the program leaves the scope where the `unique_ptr` is created, the object is deleted, no questions asked.

It's a lot to take in, I'll grant, but I hope it'll all sink in soon. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

**You should use `boost::shared_ptr` instead of `std::auto_ptr`.**

`auto_ptr` and `shared_ptr` simply keep an instance of the pointer and because they are local stack objects they get deallocated when they go out of scope. Once they are deallocated they call delete on internal pointer.

Simple example, the actuall `shared_ptr` and `auto_ptr` are more sophisticated (they have methods for assignment and conversion/access to internal pointer):

```
template <typename T>
struct myshrdptr
{
    T * t;
    myshrdptr(T * p) : t(p) {}
    ~myshrdptr()
    {
        cout << "myshrdptr deallocated" << endl;
        delete t;
    }

    T * operator->() { return t; }
};

struct AB
{
    void dump() { cout << "AB" << endl; }
};

void testShrdptr()
{
    myshrdptr<AB> ab(new AB());
    ab->dump();
    // ab out of scope destructor called
    // which calls delete on the internal pointer
    // which deletes the AB object
}
```

From somewhere else:

```
int main()
{
   testShrdptr();
   cout << "done ..." << endl;
}
```

output something like (you can see that the destructor is called):

```
AB
myshrdptr deallocated
done ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to understand `auto_ptr` and its relation to garbage-collected references, you should really try to see the underlying pattern:

In C++, all local objects have their destructors called when they go out of scope. This can be harnessed to clean up memory. *For example*, we could write a class which, in its constructor, is given a pointer to heap-allocated memory, and in its destructor, frees this pointer.

That is pretty much what `auto_ptr` does. (Unfortunately, `auto_ptr` also has some notoriously quirky semantics for assignment and copying)

It's also what `boost::shared_ptr` or other smart pointers do. There's no magic to any of those. They are simply classes that are given a pointer in their constructor, and, as they're typically allocated on the stack themselves, they'll automatically go out of scope at some point, and so their destructor is called, which can delete the pointer you originally passed to the constructor. You can write such classes yourself. Again, no magic, just a straightforward application of C++'s lifetime rules: When a local object goes out of scope, its destructor is called.

Many other classes cut out the middleman and simply let the same class do both allocation and deallocation. For example, `std::vector` calls `new` as necessary to create its internal array -- and in its destructor, it calls `delete` to release it.

When the vector is copied, it takes care to allocate a new array, and copy the contents from the original one, so that each object ends up with its own private array.

`auto_ptr`, or smart pointers in general, aren't the holy grail.  They don't "solve" the problem of memory management. They are one useful part of the recipe, but to avoid memory management bugs and headaches, you need to understand the underlying pattern (commonly known as [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)) -- that is, whenever you have a resource allocation, it should be tied to a local variable which is given responsibility for also cleaning it up.

Sometimes, this means calling `new` yourself to allocate memory, and then passing the result to an `auto_ptr`, but more often, it means not calling `new` in the first place -- simply create the object you need on the stack, and let it call `new` as required internally. Or perhaps, it doesn't even need to call `new` internally. The trick to memory management is really to just rely on local stack-allocated objects instead of heap allocations. Don't use `new` by default.

Answer (score 1):

Choose an imperative language (such as C, C++, or ADA) that provides pointer types.

Redesign that language to abolish pointer types, instead allowing programmers to define recursive types directly.

Consider carefully the issue of copy semantics vs reference semantics. Implement an interpreter for the language using DrRacket .